# Getting error while running Dropbox sample Dbroulette - error in loading photos

Tags: xcode4, dropbox-api

I am using the below code to load the photos from Dropbox but getting error "error loading photos" Please find the below lines of code and suggest

```
NSString* appKey = @"myappkey";
NSString* appSecret = @"myappSecret";
NSString *root = @"sandbox";
```

Comment: use `NSString *root = kDBRootAppFolder;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat general error that is reported whenever one of several things goes wrong. For instance:

- parseMetadataWithRequest fails because metadata wasn't returned as expected
- requestDidLoadMetadata fails because the request itself failed
- requestDidLoadThumbnail fails because the request itself failed

You'll need to look at the stack to see what is actually failing in particular.